# Notify RecyclerView adapter database changed

Tags: android, database, android-fragments, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

My `MainActivity` calls a fragment,

```
@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1),
                    "placeHolderFragmentTag")
            .commit();
}
```

`placeholderFragment` that fills a `RecyclerView` with an adapter,

```
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

@Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            dbHelper.openDataBase();

            adapterUpcomingGames = new AdapterUpcomingGames(retrieveGames(dbHelper.getUpcomingGames()));
        }
```

`adapterUpcomingGames`. The adapter gets data from a database that the user has entered, being a list of upcoming sporting events.

```
@Override   // still placeholderFragment
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

            mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext()));
            mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

            switch(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER))
            {
                case 1:     // This will be upcoming games
                    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapterUpcomingGames);
                    break;
                case 2:     // This will be past games
                    AdapterPastGames adapterPastGames;
                    adapterPastGames = new AdapterPastGames(retrieveGames(dbHelper.getPastGames()));
                    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapterPastGames);
                    break;
                default:    // Default is, well, anything that will work.
                    adapterUpcomingGames1 = new AdapterUpcomingGames(retrieveGames(dbHelper.getGames()));
                    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapterUpcomingGames1);
            }

            newGame.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0){

                    Intent createGame = new Intent(getActivity(),
                            ActivityCreateGame.class);
                    startActivity(createGame);
                    adapterUpcomingGames.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });

            setRetainInstance(true);
        }
```

With this view, there is an button to add games i.e. modify the database. I am achieving this by calling a new activity, `activityCreateGame`, that hosts a fragment,

```
@Override // activityCreateGame
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_game);

    fragmentCreateGame = new FragmentCreateGame();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .attach(fragmentCreateGame)
            .replace(R.id.newGameContainer, fragmentCreateGame)
            .commit();

    restoreActionBar();
}
```

`fragmentCreateGame`, that allows the user to enter in the desired information, and then append that to the database. The user saves this information using an option on the navbar within that activity.

```
@Override  // activityCreateGame
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                finish();
                break;
            case R.id.action_save:
                // check if an error has occured
                if (fragmentCreateGame.CreateNewGame())
                {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, R.string.toast_success_game_create,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();

                    finish();
                }
                else{
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, R.string.toast_failed_game_create,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                }
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

That action finishes the `activityCreateGame`. Now, how do I go about notify the adapter, back in `placeholderFragment` that the database has been updated and thus update the `RecyclerView` to update itself?

Comment: Post some code to help understand

Comment: From the sounds of it, consider a custom built listener from an interface, or [Activity for Reuslt](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)

Comment: I was wondering if there may have been something like that. I've added some code, but I will take a look at that also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From looking at your code, I can think of three solutions for you. In order of (my opinion) quality of the solution from least to best.

1. Move your fragment `fragmentCreateGame` to be hosted by you first activity
2. [Start Activity For Result](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)
3. Use [Otto Event Bus](http://square.github.io/otto/). I would recommend otto. Especially if you may have multiple objects listening to an event.

First add Otto to your project. In your `build.gradle`, add this to your dependancies.

```
dependencies {
   ....
   compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.6'
   ....
}
```

In your activity that needs notified, add this at the beginning of your onCreate:

```
 Bus bus = new Bus();
 bus.register(this);
```

Then, create an "event" class. It is just an object you pass to notify subscribers. You can add info to these too, to pass more info.

```
public class SomeCoolEvent{
      private String yourWisdom;
      public SomeCoolEvent(String yourWisdom){
           this.yourWisdom = yourWisdom;
      }

      public String getWisdom(){
          return yourWisdom;
      }
 }
```

Then, in your class that is doing something to notify other classes, do this:

```
Bus bus = new Bus();
bus.post(new SomeCoolEvent(yourWisdomStringFromThisClass));
```

Now, *back* to your first activity,  add a method that is annotated with `@Subscribe`

```
 @Subscribe
 public void onAnyMethodNameYouWantCauseItDoesntMatter(SomeCoolEvent event){
       //this will be called when ANY class calls bus.post(SomeCoolEvent)
       String boomYouAreNotified = event.getWisdom();
  }
```

On your `@Subscribe` method, few things to note. 
* The method name does not matter, so give it something that makes sense to you. I like to prefix it with "`on`" because its like a callback. 
* The method must be `public` and return `void`. 
* You are not explicitly calling this methods, so some IDE's may appear that it is unused. Android studio will let you fix that with "ALT + ENTER" then select "_ignore warnings for methods annotated with Subscribe". 
* You should call `bus.unregister(this)` on destroy. 
* You can have multiple classes listening to one post.

Now things can get more complicated if you start running on different threads. If you do, there are solutions to this at the bottom of the Otto page I provided.

Comment: Otto is probably a little over me right now. But I'll look at it. Done some modifications and I've got the ActivityForResult working pretty nicely, but the RecyclerView isn't updating. The adapter seems to be getting the notifyDataSetChanged, but no update is happening to the view.

Comment: @JoshuaSutherland Cause you are not adding any items to your adapter. When you are creating your adapter, you are querying your database. That works for the first. But when you call notifiyDataSetChanged, it doesn't call that again. You need to create a ArrayList of your data, then create your adapter, and pass this list in. Then add new data to this list, then call notifyDataSetChanged.

Comment: OK. That makes sense. What would be best in this instance then? Should I just requery the database on RESULT_OK?

Comment: Yes. Just be mindful of your instances of the adapter, listView, and list. If your re-query the list, and set the list to your result your adapter may have issues "seeing" this change. If so, just re-create the adapter and set it to your list view.

Comment: So if you can manage all your instances just _add_ your items to the list. Not _setting_ them to the list.